# Motor monitoring over temporary connection

Tags: dc-motor

I have an application where I need to determine whether a DC motor that is used as a vibrator is operating correctly. Normally this would be a straightforward problem that could be solved using an accelerometer. The problem with using an accelerometer for my application is the motor is mounted to a mobile structure that is passed down an assembly line like setup. All connections to the mobile assembly and motor need to be temporary. They also need to be made in an automated fashion (no human in the loop).

The motor power connection is a little simpler, the current setup uses copper plates and the weight of the mobile structure to make the connection. Would it be possible to send dynamic signals over a similar type of connection? On paper it looks like it would work, but it seems like noise might be an issue. There is also the fact that all of the connections are temporary, so there may be inconsistencies that would be hard to resolve.

Can anyone think of a better way to determine the health of the motor that would work in this type of an application?

Comment: Why an accelerometer instead of a piezo?

Comment: What do you mean by piezo? If I remember correctly piezo's are used in accelerometers.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Piezoelectric_sensor

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams [See here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Accelerometer#Structure)

Comment: "Modern accelerometers are often small micro electro-mechanical systems (MEMS) ..."

Comment: Maybe add a series resistor and measure the current going through the motor as you try to power it?

Comment: Can you allow a little power to be taken from the motor connections in order to feed a small circuit on the mobile assembly? Can you also modify the power feeding the track which the mobile assembly sits on to make data reception via the contact plates more favourable? If so what is the voltage and current of the motor nominally? Also what is the reliability of the contact system? No data if no motor connected etc..

Comment: @Andyaka Yes, power can be drawn from the motor connections to feed a small circuit. The supply voltage is 12V and current is 15A. The reliability of the contact system is a definite source of concern. The weight of the mobile assembly can vary pretty significantly, so I'm not sure how good of a connection is maintained under all conditions. It is also operating in a caustic environment with lots of chemicals (don't know the complete list), so I'm not sure if the copper contact will oxidize or not.

Comment: Assuming a motor with brushes. Instead of measuring the mechanical vibration of the motor, you might be able to measure the current varying due to commutation. Every half rotation or so that the motor makes, the current will be shortly interrupted and you might be able to measure this at the far end. If you can measure these variations, you can also get an indication of RPM's and health would be more or less propotional to \$\frac{RPM}{V×I}\$

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the weight of the structure, you could have an arrangement of pogo pins to connect a data link; this works fine as long as the device is firmly enough connected. I'd suggest a differential type of data link like RS485 or CAN, although if the connection is short and secure you should be able to get I2C to work.

Obviously if the thing is vibrating you have to make sure it's not vibrating enough to break the spring-loaded pogo connection. And the pins have to align mechanically - conical or sloped guide surfaces can do this. Normally you'd clip it in place; magnets may also work for you.

Answer (score 1):

A lot of the other answers are suggesting digital communication across the link, which is a potential option, but it does require more hardware, and something to handle the communication on the mobile structure.

Something that may be a little simpler:

Measure the resistance of the total motor circuit after each new connection is made (prior to turning the motor on). By knowing that resistance and the armature current I know the voltage drop across each connection point and the armature coil of the motor. I can then calculate the speed of the motor using it's relationship with the EMF voltage which gives me the following equation (derived from \$V_{in}=E_a+Ia*R_t\$):

\$\omega_m=(V_{in} - I_a*R_t) / K_m\$

\$w_m\$ = motor speed

\$V_in\$ = input voltage

\$I_a\$ = armature current

\$R_t\$ = total circuit resistance

\$K_m\$ = motor magnetic constant.

The above method would at least be able to get a rough estimate of the motor speed, which under drastic fault condition would most likely change. It can also all be done from the static side of the connection. The one thing that it doesn't capture is if there is anything dynamic about the connection while the motor is running (the mobile structure hopping)

Answer (score 1):

<sub>**Assumptions:**</sub>

- <sub>*The device under test is expected to vibrate within a given range of amplitudes and frequencies*</sub>
- <sub>*The device has some reflective surface visible on the assembly line, while it is on the powered copper plates.*</sub>

---

While the method of measuring current consumption by the DUT, mentioned in other posts, is perhaps the least complicated solution, here is an alternative proposal for a non-contact method.

- Fix a low intensity laser to be incident upon any reflective surface of the device when the device moves into position on the copper plates on the assembly line. Angle the laser to strike the surface at an incline. A 1 mW laser diode will be more than sufficient, any visible laser color will do.
- Fix a PIN photodiode, phototransistor or other photosensor on the reflection path of the laser, aligning it by sight.
- Sense the incident laser beam via the photodiode, and capture both frequency and amplitude variation.

Basically, as the DUT vibrates, so will the reflected laser beam. This will cause its intensity as sensed by the PIN diode / other photosensor to vary with the intensity of vibration, and at the frequency of vibration.

This method has the advantage of being easily set up, causes and requires no change to the electrical behavior of the DUT, and does not add either physical weight or power load to the DUT. Hence it will measure the behavior of the vibrating motor / device without actually modifying the vibration in any discernible way.

No contacts to get oxidized or require cleaning, which is an added benefit in a mass production environment.

Answer (score 0):

The are lots of ways to provide data over a temporary electrical link, or over some other type of link. Some ideas:

- use a property of the current drawn by the motor, as user25093 suggests
- modulate some HF signal onto the motor power lines
- use an RF modue, RFM73 or NRF24L01 or similar
- use IR
- use ultrasound
- use extra connections for a data line

The last option would probably my least favorite choice, because it adds hardware and is likely to be very unreliable.

Answer (score 0):

**Here's my suggestion.** Steal a little power from the 12V feed to the motor on the sled. This can be used to create a stable d.c. supply on the sled for electronics to process the accelerometer. I say accelerometer but if you change the sensor that detects/measures vibration, this method will be able to cope with changes.

Whatever the sensor is it should be digitized with an ADC. You are going to need a small microprocessor on board so that the "reading" is substantiated with enough bits to provide a highly secure and relaible data information package.

How much data do you need to transmit? Quite possibly, very little because the micro could decide if the vibrations are operating within reasonable limits and basically you are transmitting one very secure bit = "good" or "bad".

Frequency modulation should provide a decent means of getting data through the sled contacts and I believe that you should get at least one decent data packet transmission at least every tenth of a second and quite possibly hundreds a second should that be necessary.

So far, the sled steals some power from the contacts (it could even have a rechargeable battery should the "system" require set-up tests), an ADC connected to the vibration transducer feeds a micro, the micro decides if the data = good or bad and this single quality bit is made secure with a large error check code. This "packet" feeds a low power FM modulator and this signal is superimposed on the 12V that feeds the motor.

**Additions.** The motor shouldn't conduct the FM signal so a DC pass/ AC block circuit needs to be in series with the motor. A similar circuit is needed at the power feed circuit off the sled. Data can be collected and demodulated with a fairly simple circuit and this demodulated data checked for integrity and a relay would indicate "good vibrations" (anyone a fan of the Beach Boys?) or bad vibrations.

**More additions.** The raw data can also be transmitted as well as the "refined" good/bad data.

**What are the chances of it working?** I'm certain I could get it working and the OP has to decide whether it's worth investing in this development because it'll take at least 1 man month to design and probably cost £2k in bits and pieces. Is it worth it? Is there a wider requirement for taking information off the sled that can "reduce" the cost impact for just this one requirement?